# Parse error: Unexpected $THIS (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I don`t now much about PHP and trying to run a Telegram bot but i get this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) on line 101
$me = yield $this->get_self();

```
$userID = isset($update['message']['from_id']) ? $update['message']['from_id']:'';
$msg = isset($update['message']['message']) ? $update['message']['message']:'';
$msg_id = isset($update['message']['id']) ? $update['message']['id']:'';
$me = yield $this->get_self();
$me_id = $me['id'];
$info = yield $this->get_info($update);
$chatID = $info['bot_api_id'];
$type2 = $info['type'];
$creator = 2222222222;
$admins = array(2222222223, 2222222224);
```

Comment: What is `$this`? You can't use `$this` outside of a class.

Comment: `$me = yield $MadelineProto->getSelf();`  This is madeline docs, but I've seen people using $This 
none worked for me